# Is there a way to get the VMs and its flavor size from all openstack projects using cli tools?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

**Objective :** My objective is to generate a report with all the VMs running on the openstack instance (from all projects) with its flavor size. My Environment is running Red hat openstack OSP 8 (Liberty).

**Question/Issue:** Is there a way to get the server and its flavor size from all projects? We can get the server list from all projects using OpenStack server "openstack server list --all-projects" but this does not give the flavor size of each VM. 
I thought of writing a simple for loop taking the *server list* output and passing it to *openstack server show* command but the server show command does not show details from other projects,it only shows for admin.

Basically, I need the report similar to the table in "Horizon -> System -> Instances" (dashboard/admin/instances/) which shows the instances from all projects. I would prefer to stick with cli tools to generate the info.

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using nova cli "*nova list --fields name,flavor --all-tenants*". I could not find any options to list flavor using openstack unified cli.